# Time efficiency by eliminating three for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pandas, apply

I have the a script similar to this:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

FA = []
FB = []
Value = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
df_save = pd.DataFrame(index=['min','max'])
days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
numbers = list(range(24))   # FA.unique()
mix = '(pairwise combination of days and numbers, i.e. 0Monday,0Tuesday,...1Monday,1Tuesday,....)' 'I dont know how to do this combination btw'

def Calculus():
    global min,max
    min = df['Value'][boolean].min()
    max = df['Value'][boolean].max()

for i in range(1000):
    FA.append(random.randrange(0,23,1))
    FB.append(random.choice(days))
    Value.append(random.random())

df['FA'] = FA
df['FB'] = FB
df['FAB'] = df['FA'].astype(str) + df['FB'].astype(str)
df['Value'] = Value

mix_factor = df['FA'].astype(str) + df['FB'].astype(str)

for i in numbers:
    boolean = df['FA'] == i
    Calculus()
    df_save[str(i)] = [min,max]

for i in days:
    boolean = df['FB'] == i
    Calculus()
    df_save[str(i)] = [min,max]

for i in mix_factor.unique():
    boolean = df['FAB'] == i
    Calculus()  #
    df_save[str(i)] = [min,max]
```

My question is: there is another way to do  the same but more time efficiently? My real data (df in this case) is a csv with millions of rows and this three loops are taking forever.
Maybe using 'apply' but I never have worked with it before.

Any insight will be very appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You need to [profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code to know which method is taking up the most time.

Comment: @RafaelC I will edit my post

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I will try that, but I know that those three for loops are consuming the most part of the time

Answer (score -2):

You could put all three loops into one, depending on what your exact code is. Is there a parameter for calculus? If not, putting them into one would allow you to have to run Calculus() less